# Weighted average using dates

Tags: excel, date, formula, average

I have data which shows the number of apartments under construction, and their estimated completion date.

Is there a way to calculate the weighted average completion date; e.g. If I have 10 apartments expected to be completed on 1.1.2024, and 10 apartments completed on 1.1.2026, the weighted average of these would be 1.1.2025

Comment: I believe you might need a start date. In top of that, if both types of apartments are finished on the first on January, why would the average be somewhere in May? :-)

Comment: Have you tried the usual weighted average formula for Excel - in this case, something like: =SUMPRODUCT(Quantities,Dates)/SUM(Quantities)

Comment: With builders, won't that be 1.1.27 ?

Comment: The average is not 1.1.2025 because 2024 has 366 days while 2025 only has 365. It falls half way through 31.12.2024.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` and `SUM` like the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(finish_dates, respective_number_of_items)/SUM(total_number_of_items)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I give this a vote. Because leap years come into play the actual answer is 31-Dec-2024 12:00 which is correct.